# durandal with knockout not working

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

I have a problem. I use durandal template with knockout.js. When I trying to pass a data from my viewmodel to the view, nothing happens. I see permanently loading.

**That's my viewmodel:**

```
define(['knockout', 'common/urlconfig', 'plugins/http', 'plugins/router', 'common/userService', 'durandal/app'],
    function(ko, urlconfig, http, router, userService, app) {
        "use strict";

        function article(data) {
            this.Id = ko.observable(data.Id);
            this.Description = ko.observable(data.Description);
            this.Author = ko.observable(data.Author);
            this.Tags = ko.observable(data.Tags);
        }
       // ko.applyBindings(appViewArticles);
        return {
            articles: articles,
            displayName: 'Articles viewer',
            showMessage: app.showMessage('it\'s works!'),
            Id: Id,
            Description: Description,
            Author: Author,
            Tags: Tags,

            activate: function () {
                var self = this;
                self.articles = ko.observableArray([]);
                var promise = $.getJSON("/api/article", function (allData) {
                    var mappedArticles = $.map(allData, function (i) { return new article(i) });
                    self.articles(mappedArticles);
                });
                return promise;
            }
        };

    });
```

and **my view:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <h2 data-bind="text: 'Welcome, ' + userName() + '!'"></h2>
    </div>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr><td>ID</td><td>Description</td><td>Author</td><td>Tags</td></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: articles">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: Id"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Description"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Author"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Tags"></td>
            </tr> 
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Do you have a userName observable prop in your viewModel?

Comment: I have no errors in the console

Answer (score 1):

When I edit my **viewmodel** like this:

```
define(['knockout', 'common/urlconfig', 'plugins/http', 'durandal/app'],
    function (ko, urlconfig, http, app) {
        var articles = ko.observableArray([]);
        http.get(urlconfig.articlesUrl).then(function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(key, item) {
                articles.push(item);
            });
        }).fail(function () {
            app.showMessage('Server error!', 'Error',['OK']);
        });
        return {
            articles: articles
        };
    });
```

and **view** like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr><td>ID</td><td>Description</td><td>Author</td><td>Tags</td></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: articles">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: description"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: author"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: tags"></td>
            </tr> 
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

it worked perfectly! =)

Comment: You should know that the module will not be unloaded even if you deactivate the view. If I'm not mistaken, this means that the data you just retrieved will stay in memory even when it's not used, and will not be refreshed if you reactivate the view. This might be what you want, but since it's very often not desirable behavior, I thought I'd point it out. FYI, the alternative is to define the module as a constructor function. The function will remain loaded, but the data of the instances created from that function can be garbage collected when the view is deactivated.

Answer (score 0):

edit:

try

```
    return {
        articles: ko.observableArray([]),
        displayName: 'Articles viewer',
        showMessage: app.showMessage('it\'s works!'),


        activate: function () {
            var self = this;

            var promise = $.getJSON("/api/article", function (allData) {
                var mappedArticles = $.map(allData, function (i) { return new article(i) });
                self.articles(mappedArticles);
            });
            return promise;
        }
    };
```

Comment: I don't have userName in my viewModel

Comment: It's not help. It's make a reference error "articles is not defined"